# How does the Lua mutate assignment patch work?

Tags: lua, operators, compound-assignment

I followed [this page](http://lua-users.org/files/wiki_insecure/power_patches/5.1-work6/mutate.patch), and got an metamethod __mutate_asn. This is my test code.

```
local mt = {}
mt.__mutate_asn = function(a, b)
    print(a, b)
    return a + b
end

debug.setmetatable(0, mt)

a = 1
b = 2
a:=b

print(a)
```

output:
    1 2
    1
"a" never be changed.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's difficult to know by just looking at the patch.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mutating any numbers in the statement

```
a:=b
```

you are mutating global variables. So, perhaps you need:

```
setmetatable(_G, mt)
```